# Keep on getting missing dna block error and fbx file can't open in any program

Tags: error

I have been working in blender but one day I got a missing DNA block error and I tried to append it, recover from last session, and everything to recover it but I had to recover from auto-save which the last one was a couple days ago. So I decided to start exporting a backup fbx file which worked well until today when I got the missing DNA block error again but the fbx file won't open properly in any program so it's probably corrupted and the last auto-save was a long time ago and I can't redo my progress. I am wondering if anyone knows what's wrong with my fbx file or can knows how to fix my .blend file (if anyone knows how to stop my file from having the missing dna block error every other save would be helpful to thank you)

download for blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D0lWYPduxGgOmRZV7qsq7zzpUe3TSACF/view?usp=sharing

download for fbx file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1htCXmNDDH38yFKHf863_QLRkI2M6RjAq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So I downloaded both of those files and looked at them in a hex viewer. Your fbx file contains all zeros. Your blend file  has a little header info, and then has all zeros. There is no recoverable data. Sorry.

Comment: do you know how this happens